# What is the surface area of a plane on a sphere like Earth?

Tags: differential-geometry, area, surfaces

If I have a $1 \text{km} $ x $1 \text{km} $ plain of grass, then the surface area is $1 \text{km}{^2} $.

Well, no, because the Earth isn't a flat plane but rather a sphere that's curved. The surface area will be a tiny bit bigger but by just how much exactly? Is there a formula to find the surface area of a portion of a sphere's surface?

PS: I already know the Earth is oblate. For the purpose of this question just assume it's a perfect sphere of radius $6371 \text{km}$ with no imperfections (mountains, valleys, etc).

Comment: No, that's rather a confused title, sorry. Define a "1km x 1km plain" on a sphere, please!

Comment: Maybe [area of a spherical segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_sector#Area)?

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205927/how-to-calculate-the-area-covered-by-any-spherical-rectangle) is a nice formula: area of a "spherical rectangle" is $4R^2 \sin^{-1} \left(\tan \left(\dfrac l {2R}\right)\tan \left(\dfrac w {2R}\right)\right)$. Putting those in [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4+*6371%5E2+arcsin%28tan%281%2F%282*6371%29%29%5E2%29) yields an area so close to $1 \,km^2$, there is only an excess of $41\, cm^2$.

Comment: There is no "square" (a shape bounded by 4 "straight lines" with 4 right angle) on the earth.